# Laravel Dusk Connection refused after clear install using Sail

Tags: php, laravel, selenium, laravel-dusk, laravel-sail

- Dusk Version: v6.15.0
- Sail Version: v1.7.0
- Laravel Version: v8.43.0
- PHP Version: 8.0.5
- Docker Engine Version: 20.10.6
- O.S.: macOs BigSur 11.3.1

#### Scenario:

After a clear install of Dusk on a new Laravel project that uses Sail a "Connection Refused" error is thrown

```
./vendor/bin/sail artisan dusk
PHPUnit 9.5.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 00:00.855, Memory: 20.00 MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"browserName":"chrome","goog:chromeOptions":{"args":["--window-size=1920,1080","--disable-gpu","--headless"]}}]},"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"args":["--window-size=1920,1080","--disable-gpu","--headless"]}}}

Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused

/var/www/html/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:332
/var/www/html/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:135
/var/www/html/tests/DuskTestCase.php:46
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:218
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:234
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:219
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:97
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:65
/var/www/html/tests/Browser/ExampleTest.php:21

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

I followed all instructions I found at [Sail Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail) and at [Dusk Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk) with no changes. My docker environment was completely cleared from old images and containers used by Laravel Sail Projects.

At first glance I tried editing anything on the project simply running dusk, so the **APP_URL** was the default one on .env file

```
APP_URL=http://selenium.test
```

But, after I read the docs at [Dusk Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk) the following sentence "*Next, set the APP_URL environment variable in your application's .env file. This value should match the URL you use to access your application in a browser.*" I set it to the one I use on the browser

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

#### Steps To Reproduce:

1. `curl -s "https://laravel.build/selenium?with=selenium" | bash`
2. `cd selenium && ./vendor/bin/sail up -d`
3. `./vendor/bin/sail composer require --dev laravel/dusk`
4. `./vendor/bin/sail artisan dusk:install`
5. `./vendor/bin/sail artisan dusk`
6. Try changing the APP_URL in .env and run the 5 point again

I cannot figure out why the problem occurs

Comment: Also try `artisan dusk:chrome-driver <chrome version>`

Comment: thank you @apokryfos, tried `sail artisan dusk:chrome-driver 90.0.4430.24`, same error after that

Comment: Try just the major version `90`

Comment: It installs the same version

Comment: @SamDroid Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question so you are probably (I hope) not trying to solve this any more. I have been trying to solve a different issue but thought I could provide a few pointers.

First, when using Sail, to run Dusk you should use:

```
./vendor/bin/sail dusk
```

There is no `artisan` in that command.

Second, for the default install of Sail, the container name of the app is `laravel.test` so that should be the value to use in your `APP_URL` env var.